# What should I do with a workshop paper which is peer reviewed, but only available on the workshop website?

Tags: publications, peer-review, conference, paper-submission, workshop

I presented a paper in a workshop in CS. The workshop was related to a good conference, and they had a peer review system for evaluating the papers. But they do not have a proceeding and only made the pdf files available on their website.

Does it mean that my work is now considered **published**? or i should still try to send it to a conference venue for proper publication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works that appear in unpublished proceedings are not (generally) considered published, so such works can be submitted elsewhere, e.g., conferences with published proceedings, journals, etc. (Exceptions may arise if copyright was assigned, but workshops with unpublished proceedings shouldn't be asking for copyright.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on that, please? Does it mean i can submit it to a conference without changing anything from the content or i need to revise/add/improve it?

Comment: The work is not published, you can do whatever you like with it.